# Should I quit my current job, which I will be fired from soon, this week to prepare for an interview I have next week?

Tags: interviewing, resignation, united-kingdom, probation

I have a bit of dilemma that I was hoping you guys could help with. I have 1 month left of my probation period at my first job after leaving university, for various reasons I do not think I will pass. I’m thinking of leaving before I am let go so that future employers will not be aware.

I have a final stage interview next week for a job I’m really excited for, but I do not think I will be able to adequately prepare this week for it as I will have a heavy week at work. Considering I am thinking of leaving anyway, shall I go ahead and leave early?

Just about me, I luckily live with my parents and I have around 3k savings so I can afford to be unemployed for a bit if I am thrifty. Also I live in the UK if this makes a difference.

Comment: You are putting too much emphasis on the "let go" vs "I quit". While you are on probation all you have to say in future interviews is that it just didn't work out, so parted ways during probation, as that's what probation is for. But also I VTC as asking for help on specific choices is off topic here.

Comment: You say you have one month left on your probation period? How long was your probation period? 3 months? 6 months? One year? Also from your username, it seems you're an Android software developer. Is that correct?

Answer (score 7):

That really depends on how certain you are that you will get the boot.

- Quitting while not having a new job lined up is not a great idea

versus

- Quitting looks indeed better then being fired and it's easier to answer "so why did you leave your job at XXX" which inevitably will come up in most interviews

If you are very certain you will be dismissed, pro-actively resigning is not a bad idea. It also makes live for your current employer easier, so they might appreciate it and be a little more generous with a reference.

However, make sure that you fully understand your current situation. I found that many people are astonishingly bad in assessing how close they are to getting fired (both under-worry and over-worry is quite common).

Comment: The OP is in the probation period, he can simply answer that he don't see himself in that position/role/whatever. After all, also the probation period is two way process, the employer test the employee, but also the employee test the employer. Sometime you just land in a work that don't fit for you (for any reason)

Comment: Fully agree with last paragraph.  And, "if you [think that you] are 'about to get fired'" from *this* job, how's the grass gonna be greener?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you quit tomorrow, you'd still need to work out your notice period. In my experience, that's usually a week while still on probation, so quitting is unlikely to help you prepare for your interview.

It's good that you have a safety net, but I think you also need to ask yourself what you'll do if you quit now and *don't* get the job you're interviewing for.

Unless you have less than a weeks notice and you're really sure you'll land the new job, or you know you can financially cope with a more extended period of unemployment, I'd suggest that you keep your current job and put in some additional hours to prepare for the interview around your work hours.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! One big thing I’m worried about is being let go before having a chance to quit. In which case having that I was let go on my resume will be far worse would it not? And my notice period is around a month, and since I have a month left, I’m thinking of putting it in now.

Comment: They can fire you even if you give notice, if they really don’t like you.

Comment: Actually @gnasher729, doing that without a LOT of evidence that you were going to be fired for cause before you handed notice, will more than likely be considered unfair dismissal in the UK. It's very much illegal and would easily land them in hot water. Unless formal disciplinary action is already in motion, they cannot just fire the OP because they don't like them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give any details of why you think you will be let go, as Hilmar says above, people are often very bad at judging their situation. If you feel you haven't been performing well-enough, arrange a meeting with your manager to discuss the issues, try not to pre-empt what they will say (i.e. prefer "I wasn't happy with this bit of a work I did. How can I improve?" vs "The work I did for this was terrible") and listen to how they reply. Maybe they will think the issues can be worked on by either you or them and they want you to stay or maybe your analysis is correct, in which case the door is then open to talk about leaving. The company will probably prefer for you to leave my mutual consent, rather than having to ask you to leave and this will look better on your CV.

If the issue is more of a personality one, that is a harder discussion to have (lots of good questions on that topic here) but you will need to decide whether it is easier to leave but may still be worth having that discussion.

Answer (score -1):

In the U.K.: Don’t quit. It is financially a lot better for you to be fired. And expect your plans to go wrong. Job interview doesn’t mean you get the job. And depending on when you started, even if they don’t want you, the company can be nice and put you on furlough so you still get paid, so be nice to them and don’t upset anyone. (This is specific to April 2020. Many usual rules don’t apply).

Comment: Thanks for the advice @gnasher729. What I’m really worried about is how being fired will affect interviewing in the future. If I leave I at least truthfully get to say that I felt it wasn’t working out.

Comment: this (generally, if you're a post-corona time person reading this [and isn't it nice to think there is a post-corona time? or is that optimistic?]) isn't true - you're not liable for payments from your company if you've only worked a few weeks? but you're right, they will probably not need to fire you given the government money available to keep people on.